# setTimeout behaves different than a promise, using $httpBackend.flush()

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a weird situation where a setTimeout behaves different than a promise, and I am not sure why. I have this test which works:

```
    it('should get comments with promptid', function () {

      var url = encodeURI('/api/v1/comments?filter={"promptId":"59dd4e7c714d3e34de04030a"}&populate=[]');

      httpBackend.expectGET(url).respond(comments);

      setTimeout(function () {
        httpBackend.flush();
      }, 100);

      return myService.getCommentsByPromptId("59dd4e7c714d3e34de04030a").then(function (response) {

        expect(response.length).to.equal(1);
        expect(response[0]._id).to.equal(comments[0]._id);
      });

    });
```

however, if I try to do the above like so:

```
    it('should get comments with promptid', function () {


      var url = encodeURI('/api/v1/comments?filter={"promptId":"59dd4e7c714d3e34de04030a"}&populate=[]');

      httpBackend.expectGET(url).respond(comments);

      const prom = myService.getCommentsByPromptId("59dd4e7c714d3e34de04030a");

      httpBackend.flush();

      return prom.then(function (response) {
        expect(response.length).to.equal(1);
        expect(response[0]._id).to.equal(comments[0]._id);
      });

    });
```

I get a timeout after 2000ms in the second case. Any reason why? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Looks like httpBackend is a mutable shared object, maybe another `it` method also uses it and by the time your timeout flushes httpBackend the httpBackend got in an invalid state. Does this happen when you only have on `it`  using httpBackend?

Comment: yeah, I haven't tried this setup without using $httpBackend

Comment: You can quickly find out if it fails when you only have one `it` method in your tests (rename test dir and copy one method in a new test dir?)